Drawing Women private parts
Once I drew women boobs and I'm stressed about it that I'm going to hell. Please tell me if I'm going to hell or not. If by sincere you mean to not doing it again, and being scared of what you have done then yes I have sincerely repented as well. I don't want to go to hell plz tell me what I shall do for Allah's mercy?
